# Error while executing sql script using python sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm using python sqlite3. I created a database and now I'm using following script to create a table.

```
-- DROP TABLE master_stage."member";

CREATE TABLE master_stage."member" (
    empi varchar(100) NULL,
    buy_in varchar(200) NULL,
    birth_date date NULL,
```

But I'm getting error - unkown database "master_stage".

I used to run this script on postgresql and their master stage is the name of the schema.

Now I've to run this in sqlite3 for testing purpose. How to make it work ?

Comment: Did you [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) a database using the schema name `master_stage` first?

Comment: Or another way to look at... if you opened the database separately, it will have the schema name `main`, regardless of the filename or the schema name from another connection.

Comment: @Shawn Yea i attached now and it's working. Thanks !

Comment: @CPerkins yea got it !